# What's faster when using jQuery to check visibility, $.data() or $.is(':visible')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Today while I was writing some code for two methods that shows and hides a menu, I made a small test to see the most efficient way to check the visibility of the menu.

The results varied from a browser to another, FF 4.0b12 is faster using `$.data`, but Chrome (webkit) and Opera is faster when using `$.is(':visible')`.

I couldn't test on IE9 , because the browser kept locking on me!
Here is the test case: http://jsperf.com/data-or-display/3

So, what's the most efficient way to check visibility WITH jQuery ?

Comment: `$('whatever').is(':visible')` reads the best. I think that is what matters.

Comment: "[IE9] kept locking on me!" Thanks for the daily dose of entertainment that I needed. Some browsers just never change...

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization to me. As a reader of your code, `.is(':visible:')` is much clearer IMHO.

Comment: I agree with @Matt.. particularly with showing/hiding a menu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$('whatever').is(':visible')` reads the best. I think that is what matters. Unless you need to check hundreds of elements a second, I would not waste my time.

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

#### Donald Knuth

[Source (PDF)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.6084&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

If you must get the best performance, ditch jQuery and use native JavaScript.

Comment: I agree, but I actually wasn't going to optimize If I didn't have a lot of menus and I run few functions when they appear or hide, so it was necessary (at the cost of readability of course)

Comment: Thanks, I already assumed good programmers will point this out, that's why I wrote '**WITH** jQuery' :). Update: OMG, it was like 93% faster, I never thought it'll be that much faster!

Comment: @Maher4Ever I'm missing everything today. I'll just say, if performance is what you desire, you won't ever get as fast as native if you limit yourself to jQuery's API.

Comment: @alex I totally agree with you, I just wanted feedback on this matter and yours is much appreciated.

Comment: @Maher4Ever No worries, I hope you get the efficiency you require.

Comment: @alex this answer is WRONG. :visible and style.display != none is not the same thing. visible will take into account of a parent element isn't visible and thus neither their children will be. by using style.display != none you will get a false positive result

Answer (score 0):

Because `is(':visible')` also tests the visibility of ancestors, it *will* be faster to test `data` on elements.

It is also faster to use `data('hidden')` than `attr('data-hidden')` as the boolean values are stored as booleans and not converted to/from strings.

**Updated JSPerf:** http://jsperf.com/data-or-display/5

For the specific test case I also added a basic `.toggle()`, so that all the iteration and checking was done by jQuery, but that was still slightly slower than using an `each` and testing data. I am guessing this is a similar reason to `attr` being slower than `data` and `toggle()` checking attributes (e.g. for `display: none`).